# Silverlight client consuming WCF services - config issue in Production environment

Tags: silverlight, wcf, endpoint

We have built a silverlight client consuming a WCF service. it works absolutely perfect on our local dev boxes since both the projects WCF service + Silverlight Host App are running on Localhost and work fine.

However, in Production environment, silverlight client is hosted in a different Website and the WCF service is now hosted in a different site within the same IIS. The silverlight app is not able to invoke the service at all and after configuring WCF diagnostics on the service, we found that the service is not called at all. It seems that somehow, the endpoint (production environment) for WCF service needs to be updated in the silverlight but there does not seems to be a clear way of updating the end point in Silverlight.

Any ideas ?

Comment: There could be a problem with client access policy.

Answer (score 1):

The Silverlight-side service client is generated with several constructors: one of them takes a `Uri` parameter. Use that constructor, passing in the `Uri` that's appropriate for the production environment. (The default constructor, which you're probably using now, is hard-coded to use the uri of the service when it was added during development.)

Comment: We have different landscapes Dev, QA, Production and while moving a release from QA to Production, we possibly can not recompile the app again to point to Production URI. what is the best way to manage the production URI dyanmically ?

Comment: At runtime, you can look at `Application.Current.Host.Source`, which is the Uri of the Silverlight XAP file -- that should give you enough info to construct a separate Uri to your web service.